# Azure build agent and xamarin.android build

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, apk, build-pipeline

i have a vm on which i installed the lastest version of microsoft visual studio (16.7.3). this machine is intended to be used as a build-agent for azure devops pipelines.

i tried the following.
opened visual studio, download and open the project source, build (releasebuild) the project, archive and sign the apk and install it on the target device (android 7.0) --> this was successful. the app works as expected.

i also installed the build-agent-package (vsts-agent-win-x64-2.170.1.zip) on this machine.
i configured it and it was succesfully registered at the azure devops site.

when i run a build pipeline targetting the same project (releasebuild), the agent generates and signs the apk-package. this apk-package installs on the target device but the app does not start.
this means: no error messages, only a white screen.

i compared the two apks, they differ slightly, the inner folder structure is equal,
but some files have different sizes.

this test runs against the azure devops server 2020 rc2. but i have the same issue
using the tfs 2018 and the corresponding build agent.

could anyone give me some hints how to research this issue?

many thanks in advance

keek

Comment: hello it's not really a code issue, Stackoverflow is made for coding issues. You could try other forums such as https://android.stackexchange.com/ ,  or xda if you get no help here.

Comment: I tried to explicitly build an apk for the "armeabi-v7a" platform. this one works as expected.

Comment: the project was configured to create an apk for "armeabi-v7a" and "arm64-v8a" architecture. This is no problem when i create the apk using visual studio. But the apk created by the build pipeline does not work. I tried the option /p:AndroidSupportedAbis="armeabi-v7a". this gave me a working apk. But i'm still a bit confused - where is the difference to the visual studio build?